# Parse a floated number with parseFloat()

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, parsefloat

Hi I've got follow code:

```
keys = [
    { label: '1', key: '1' },
    { label: '2', key: '2' },
    { label: '3', key: '3' },
    { label: '4', key: '4' },
    { label: '5', key: '5' },
    { label: '6', key: '6' },
    { label: '7', key: '7' },
    { label: '8', key: '8' },
    { label: '9', key: '9' },
    { label: 'C', key: 'Delete' },
    { label: '0', key: '0' },
    { label: '.', key: '.' }
];
```

I loop my keys in an ng-repeat to build something like a calculator like this:

```
<div class="cKeys">
    <div class="cKey" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.keys" ng-click="ctrl.modifyValue(item)">{{item.label}}</div>
</div>
```

When I click on a key, I call a function with the clicked object as parameter.

```
modifyValue(obj: any) {
    let str = this.currentValue + obj.key;
    this.currentValue = parseFloat(str);
}
```

In this function, I build a string and parse it with `parseFloat()` to get a number. The `this.currentValue` is an ng-model of an input, where my number should be displayed.

So when I click follow keys: `1`, `2`, `5`, `.` (the point) and `3`, I expect the number `125.3` in my input, but there is `1253` without the point? I thought, when I use the `parseFloat()` it should show me also floatet numbers. Whats wrong?

Comment: `125.` is parsed as 125 and then you concatenate 3 to it

Comment: The '.' gets dropped as soon as it is appended, as `parseFloat('125.') === 125`.

Comment: You can get more complete an accurate help if you put a runnable [mcve] in the question using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button).

Comment: Hi @T.J.Crowder I tried it when I wrote the question, but I had some problems with the snippet (since yesterday) it doesn't work as usual (slow, and prints a lot of errors that I never saw before..) Usually I wrote snippets :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'.'` gets dropped as soon as it is appended, as `parseFloat('125.') === 125`.

Maintain two variables. One that contains the parsed result, and one that contains the concatenated string. Always parse the concatenated string:

```
modifyValue(obj: any) {
    this.concatStr += obj.key;
    this.currentValue = parseFloat(this.concatStr);
}
```

As @T.J. Crowder pointed out in the comments, this approach means that should you select the `'.'`, it will not be "forgotten" if you then select another number after it.

Comment: First line is helping not the second one. that is when you click `.` it parses back to.......! you know it.

Comment: @Jai: His point is that by maintaining the string separately, you don't lose the fact the `.` was clicked. And he's right.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder both thumbs up.

Comment: at the moment I've got the problem, that it shows now the point when I type 125. correctly in the input, but when I type another number after the (for example 3) point it delets the point and shows only 125 in case of 125.3 - whats the problem?